# Deleting a line in a txt file with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I recently made a script in which I want to delete an **EXACT** match from a txt file with node. It print's out true but doesn't actually remove the line from the txt file. I am using discord to get the argument.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but here is my script:

```
        const fs = require('fs')
        fs.readFile('notredeemed.txt', function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
                if (data.toString().match(new RegExp(`^${args[0]}$`, "m"))) {
                    fs.readFile('notredeemed.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
                      if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                      }
                      var result = data.replace(/${args[0]/g, '');
                    
                      fs.writeFile('notredeemed.txt', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
                         if (err) return console.log(err);
                      });
                    });
                      console.log("true")
```

If someone could help me I would appreciate it :)

Comment: `var result = data.replace(/${args[0]/g, '');` You can't do string interpolation in regex like that. And even if you use `regex = new Regex(\`${args[0]}\`, "g")` your `args[0]` may be a regex itself! For example, if `args[0]` is `"hi."` then it will match `"hi<any-character-here>"`.

Comment: @h-sifat has a point there. But the correct syntax to mimic your example would be `var result = data.replace(new RegExp(args[0], "g"), '');`

Comment: So what do I have to do? @h-sifat
Im kind of new so sorry if it seems like a weird question

Comment: No It's a good question. I'm working on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it very similarly as your current solution, just the regex is a little off.

Instead of just using `^` and `$` to indicate that the entire string starts and ends with the `args[0]`, I used two capture groups as the delimiters of a line.

This one matches any newline character or the beginning of the string.  Works for first line of file, and prevents partial replacement e.g. `llo` replacing `Hello`:

```
(\n|^)
```

And this one matches a carriage return or the end of the string.  This works for cases where there is no newline at the end of the file, and also prevents `Hel` replacing `Hello`:

```
(\r|$)
```

That should ensure that you are always taking out an entire line that matches your args.

I also eliminated the second `readFile` as it wasn't necessary to get it to work.

```
const fs = require("fs")

fs.readFile("notredeemed.txt", function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err

  const match = new RegExp(`(\n|^)${args[0]}(\r|$)`)

  const newFile = data.toString().replace(match, ``)

  fs.writeFile("notredeemed.txt", newFile, "utf8", function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    console.log("true")
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

Algorithm:

1. Split the file content into individual lines with your desired End of Line Flag (generally `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`)
2. Filter all the lines that you want to delete
3. Join all the filtered lines back together with the EOL flag

```js
const replacingLine = "- C/C++ addons with Node-API";

const fileContent = `- V8
- WASI
- C++ addons
- C/C++ addons with Node-API
- C++ embedder API
- C/C++ addons with Node-API
- Corepack`;

const newFileContent = replace({ fileContent, replacingLine });

console.log(newFileContent);

function replace({ fileContent, replacingLine, endOfLineFlag = "\n" }) {
  return fileContent
    .split(endOfLineFlag)
    .filter((line) => line !== replacingLine)
    .join(endOfLineFlag);
}
```

Comment: What if the data is inside of a txt file?
Like right now inside of my notredeemed.txt there is:
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
In separate lines

Comment: In that case just read the file. e.g: `const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filepath, "utf8")`. Though I recommend using the asynchronous method `fs.readFile`. I've kept the file content in a variable to make the code snippet simple to understand.